# Does the Observable.take(1) function dispose itself after taking 1?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, observer-pattern, rx-kotlin2

Does an `Observable.take(1)` function dispose itself after taking 1?

Comment: Disposes the upstream and completes the downstream.